# How to pivot_longer when I have to split up the variable names and make them form a new column?

Tags: pivot, tidyr, long-integer

I want to pivot_longer my dataset. My problem is that I don't know how to exactly specify the pivot_longer function in order to tell R that I need to split up the variable names. As I've got a pre-post-control-group design most variables end on "_t1" oder "_t2" and that is the part I wish to separate and create a new time variable from.

This is a reduced example of my dataset.

```
df <- structure(list(vp_code = c("IL1501", "IH2702", "IA1103", "EL2206", 
"AA0703", "AU0812", "IA0203", "TH1201", "EE2609", "NI0611", "SA0505", 
"NI1205", "AU1610", "LH0705", "OE0306", "ME0503", "TS1709", "IS2006", 
"IO0707", "IE0207", "IT2003", "RI0310", "EE3003", "AH2208", "IO3110", 
"AE2109", "EH2407", "AI1006", "II2008", "NA1007", "RE2907", "ER2409", 
"NO0501", "DI2402", "II1812", "EI1803", "UU0411", "IA0902", "FA0206", 
"CN1010", "RD2711", "IO2107", "IU0712", "OA0308", "OU0712", "NK1104", 
"AD2803", "ER0201", "EP0910", "RK1501", "AO2409", "SE0610", "IZ2506", 
"IE2102", "IT0401", "IP0108", "OI1408", "OR0601", "TO2109", "IP2008", 
"OR2407", "TR2408"), HTKS_test1_summe_t1 = c(7.5, 0.5, 6, 4, 
10, 4, 9.5, 9.5, 0, 9, 9.5, 9.5, 10, 9.5, 9.5, 2, 10, 8, 9.5, 
0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 9.5, 10, 0, 10, 0, 2.5, 10, 0, 0, 7, 9, 8.5, 8, 
8, 0, 1, 0, 10, 9, 10, 10, 0, 4.5, 9.5, 0, 7.5, 9.5, 1, 9.5, 
9, 10, 9, 9, 9, 10, 8, 5.5, 8.5), HTKS_test2_summe_t1 = c(5.5, 
0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 8, 3.5, 9.5, 8, 0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 0, 
0, 7.5, 0, 0, 3, 2.5, 0, 8.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 10, 9.5, 6, 2, 10, 0.5, 4.5, 0, 6, 8.5, 0, 8.5, 9.5, 6, 
9, 0, 3, 8.5, 1, 8.5, 1), HTKS_summe_gesamt_t1 = c(13, 0.5, 11, 
NA, 18, NA, 9.5, 11.5, 0, 16, 17.5, 13, 19.5, 17.5, 9.5, 2, 16, 
13, 17.5, 0, 0, 16.5, 0, NA, 12.5, 12.5, 0, 18.5, 0, 2.5, 10, 
0, 0, 9, 16, 14.5, 15, 11, 0, 1, 0, 20, 18.5, 16, 12, 10, 5, 
14, 0, NA, 18, 1, 18, 18.5, 16, 18, 9, 12, 18.5, 9, 14, NA), 
    dccs_ges_t1 = c(19, 19, 18, 6, 18, 6, 18, 18, 10, 18, 19, 
    6, 19, 21, 17, 19, 18, 18, 20, 6, 6, 18, 19, 17, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, NA, 17, 18, NA, 20, 18, 6, 6, 6, 6, 18, 
    NA, 18, 18, 18, 6, 18, 6, 18, 20, 6, 21, 18, 19, 18, 6, 18, 
    NA, 18, 18, 7), SS_summe_test1_t1 = c(9, 5, 8, 4, 90, 5, 
    5, 6.5, 5, 10, 9.5, 5, 5, 8, 5, 6, 6, 4, 10, 5, 4, 10, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 4.5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6.5, 7, 5, 7.5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9, 0, 5, 8.5, 5, 8, 9.5, 6, 10, 9, 9.5, 
    8.5, 10, 7, 9, 5.5, 4.5, 5), SS_summe_test2_t1 = c(NA, 5, 
    5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 6, 5, 9, 8.5, 5, 5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 0, 5, 
    7.5, 5, 0, 3, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 8, 8, 5, 5, 0, 
    5, 5, 0, 6.5, NA, 8.5, NA, 0, 6, 7.5, NA, 4, 10, 5, 9, 9.5, 
    9, 8.5, 9.5, 6.5, 10, 6, 4, 5), SS_summe_gesamt_t1 = c(NA, 
    10, 13, 4, 95, 5, 10, 12.5, 10, 19, 18, 10, 10, 16, 10, 11, 
    11, 9, 19, 5, 9, 17.5, 9, 5, 8, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5, 14.5, 15, 10, 12.5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 16, NA, 18, NA, 0, 11, 
    16, NA, 12, 19.5, 11, 19, 18.5, 18.5, 17, 19.5, 13.5, 19, 
    11.5, 8.5, 10), RF_MO_Gesamtsumme_t1 = c(10, 6, 9, 3, 8, 
    0, 3, 6, 4, 10, 5, 7, 8, 8, 5, 3, 11, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 0, 
    9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 6, 6, 6, 8, 4, 9, 6, 6, 6, NA, 
    9, 11, NA, 3, 7, 0, 1, 6, 2, 6, 8, 10, 5, 10, 9, 6, 5, 8, 
    NA), HTKS_test1_summe_t2 = c(NA, 5.5, 0, 0, 10, 0, 8, 2, 
    9.5, 9.5, 9, 9.5, 9.5, 10, 9, 9, 10, 9.5, 9, 10, 0, 9.5, 
    8.5, 2, 10, 8, 10, 10, 10, 9.5, 9, 10, 7, 10, 0, 10, 10, 
    9, 9, 2, 10, 10, 6, 4.5, NA, 0, 0.5, NA, 0, 9.5, 10, 0, 9.5, 
    10, 10, 9.5, 9, 9, 10, 9.5, 9.5, 9), HTKS_test2_summe_t2 = c(NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 9.5, 0, 5.5, 1, 1.5, 10, 8.5, 9, 10, 9, 9, 5, 10, 
    9.5, 1, 4, 0, 7, 4, 0, 9, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 8.5, 7, 8.5, 2.5, 
    7.5, 10, 0, 1, 9.5, 9.5, 8, 0, 7, 10, 8.5, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 7, 8.5, 0, 9.5, 10, 7, 9.5, 8.5, 4, 10, 2, 8.5, 3), HTKS_summe_gesamt_t2 = c(NA, 
    5.5, 0, 0, 19.5, 0, 13.5, 2, 11, 19.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 
    19, NA, 14, 20, 19, 10, 14, 0, 16.5, 12.5, 2, 19, 15.5, 17.5, 
    20, 18.5, 16.5, 17.5, NA, 14.5, 20, 0, 11, 19.5, 18.5, 17, 
    2, 17, 20, 14.5, 4.5, 19, 0, 0.5, 10.5, 0, 16.5, 18.5, 0, 
    19, 20, 17, 19, 17.5, 13, 20, 11.5, 18, 12), dccs_ges_t2 = c(NA, 
    19, 19, 6, 17, 6, 18, 18, 20, 16, 19, 18, 18, 17, 18, 18, 
    18, 9, 20, 19, 6, 18, 19, 17, 18, 19, 18, 18, 18, 17, 18, 
    NA, 18, 18, 20, 18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    6, 18, 18, 20, 24, 6, 21, 18, 18, 19, 17, 18, 17, 19, 18, 
    18), SS_summe_test1_t2 = c(NA, 5, 5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4, 9, 10, 
    9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9, 9, 9, 6.5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 8, 2, 5, 7, 10, 
    5, 9.5, 6, 6, 9.5, 4, 5.5, 10, 5, 10, 9, 9, 10, 8.5, 9.5, 
    10, 10, 5, 8, 5, 5, 9, 3.5, 8, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10, 9.5, 9.5, 
    8.5, 8.5, 6.5, 6, 5), SS_summe_test2_t2 = c(NA, 5, 5, 0, 
    6, 0, 5, 8, 10, 9.5, 9, 9, 8.5, 8, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 
    6, 0, 3, 8.5, 0, 10, 5, 5, 7.5, 0, 0, 6, 5, 8.5, 10, 7.5, 
    9, 6.5, 7, 10, 10, 0, 9.5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 9.5, 10, 9, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 7, 5, 5), SS_summe_gesamt_t2 = c(NA, 10, 
    10, 6, 11.5, 5, 9, 17, 20, 19, 18.5, 18.5, 17.5, 17, 15, 
    12.5, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 17, 8, 5, 10, 18.5, 5, 19.5, 11, 
    11, 17, 4, 5.5, 16, 10, 18.5, 19, 16.5, 19, 15, 16.5, 20, 
    20, 5, 17.5, 5, 5, 15, 3.5, 17.5, 20, 18, 20, 20, 20, 19.5, 
    19.5, 17.5, 15.5, 13.5, 11, 10), RF_MO_Gesamtsumme_t2 = c(NA, 
    11, 7, 1, 7, 2, 7, 11, 9, 14, 7, 8, 11, 10, 5, 9, 12, 10, 
    5, 2, 10, 8, 4, 0, 8, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9, 3, 6, 11, 10, 
    8, 3, 9, 7, 3, 9, 12, 9, 12, 7, 4, 11, 1, 6, 9, 2, 6, 9, 
    14, 8, 12, 11, 9, 7, 5, 5)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -62L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
        32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
        43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
        54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

By now I've tried a million false variants of code going in this direction:

```
data_long <- pivot_longer(df,
             cols = contains(c("_t1", "_t2")), 
             names_to = c("HTKS_test1_summe":"SS_summe_gesamt"),
             names_sep = c("_t1", "_t2"),
             values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `names_sep` you have to specify the character where you want to break the string, in your case is "_" when is followed by "t1" or "t2", to get this with regex we write `names_sep = "_(?=t[12])"`.

```r
data_long <- pivot_longer(df,
                          cols = contains(c("_t1", "_t2")), 
                          names_to = c("var_name","moment"),
                          names_sep = "_(?=t[12])",
                          values_drop_na = TRUE) 
data_long
#> # A tibble: 945 × 4
#>    vp_code var_name          moment value
#>    <chr>   <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 IL1501  HTKS_test1_summe  t1       7.5
#>  2 IL1501  HTKS_test2_summe  t1       5.5
#>  3 IL1501  HTKS_summe_gesamt t1      13  
#>  4 IL1501  dccs_ges          t1      19  
#>  5 IL1501  SS_summe_test1    t1       9  
#>  6 IL1501  RF_MO_Gesamtsumme t1      10  
#>  7 IH2702  HTKS_test1_summe  t1       0.5
#>  8 IH2702  HTKS_test2_summe  t1       0  
#>  9 IH2702  HTKS_summe_gesamt t1       0.5
#> 10 IH2702  dccs_ges          t1      19  
#> # … with 935 more rows
```

```r
data_wide_moment <- pivot_wider(data_long, names_from = moment)
data_wide_moment
#> # A tibble: 493 × 4
#>    vp_code var_name             t1    t2
#>    <chr>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 IL1501  HTKS_test1_summe    7.5  NA  
#>  2 IL1501  HTKS_test2_summe    5.5  NA  
#>  3 IL1501  HTKS_summe_gesamt  13    NA  
#>  4 IL1501  dccs_ges           19    NA  
#>  5 IL1501  SS_summe_test1      9    NA  
#>  6 IL1501  RF_MO_Gesamtsumme  10    NA  
#>  7 IH2702  HTKS_test1_summe    0.5   5.5
#>  8 IH2702  HTKS_test2_summe    0     0  
#>  9 IH2702  HTKS_summe_gesamt   0.5   5.5
#> 10 IH2702  dccs_ges           19    19  
#> # … with 483 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Oh wow thank you so so so much! What a relief ':D